# Need help with showing divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'd be glad if someone could help me once again :)

Given is the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n^2+n+1}$$ I need to show the divergence. Which way is the right? (Am I correct that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot \frac{n+1}{n^2+n+1}$$ converges? Tried it using Leibnitz)

and:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^n+3^n}$$ (again: correct that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{n}}{2^n+3^n}$$ converges? Tried it using Leibnitz)

Thank you very much!

EDIT: The second series was the wrong one, someone already helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could compare each term with $\frac{1}{2n}$:
$$\frac{n+1}{n^2 + n + 1} \ge \frac{1}{2n} \Leftrightarrow n+1 \ge \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n},$$
which is clearly valid for $n \ge 1$.
It is well known that the Harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n^2+n+1}$. To show the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$, we verify that this is an alternating series. The alternation of signs is clear, as is the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. We also need to show that the sequence $(a_n)$ is non-increasing.

One can do this in various ways. For example, one can show that the derivative of $\frac{x+1}{x^2+x+1}$ is negative when $x\gt 0$. Or else we can note that $a_n=\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{n+1}}$. If we increment $n$ by $1$, the term $n$ in the denominator is incremented by $1$, and the term $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is decremented by less than $1$, so the denominator increases.

The series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^n+3^n}$ converges. For $\frac{2^n}{2^n+3^n}\lt \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$, and the geometric series  $\sum_1^\infty\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ converges.

Because absolute convergence implies convergence, it follows that $\sum_1^\infty (-1)^n\frac{2^n}{2^n+3^n}$ converges.